# Can I convert array of models into collection of models?

Tags: laravel, laravel-collection

In  Laravel 8 Backend app with output

```
$var->toArray())
```

if $var is collection of models, then array of model values is outputted

But if $var - is array, which generated as :

```
$permissions          = Permission
    ::orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($permissionItem) use ($userPermissions) {
        return $permissionItem;
    })
    ->all();
```

$permissions - would be array of models. Can I to convert it into collection and use toArray() to it ?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you need to turn it into a collection to just turn it back into an array? also that `map` call isn't actually doing anything

Comment: Why would you convert it to a Collection just to convert it back to an array... In fact, you shouldn't need to use `->toArray()` at all; a Collection is perfectly fine, and will be converted to JSON from your backend (for example, or remain as a Collection, both of which are fine)

Comment: That is just debugging tool and I like how $var->toArray()) works for collection of models. I need array of models work in the same way

Comment: `$permissions = Permission::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();` is already a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't call `all` on your Collection. Calling `all` gives you the array of items. Just don't call `all` if you want to keep it as a Collection.

If you are not in control of that call then you would need to make a Collection from your array and then do what you want with it:

```
collect($var)->toArray()
```